# How to change file extension in Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

I have to download media files from a website which returns a video URL like this:

https://scontent-dfw5-2.cdninstagram.com/vp/1cdfc59a008aa7609b5a91d7fdf58a81/5CB6F8B1/t50.12441-16/57499829_322195418440891_1171410395492073139_n.mp4?_nc_ht=scontent-dfw5-2.cdninstagram.com

I download this video file using [flutter_downlaoder](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_downloader).

Downloaded file does not contain any extension so i have to add it myself.

I have to rename downloaded file in following format:

> [username]_[timestamp].mp4

Problem is that when i download this video file without extension and add it manually by renaming from storage directory, video plays fine but when i rename programmatically it doesn't play and gives 'Video Format Error'.

I have shared my code below. How to fix this issue?

```
Future downloadMedia(String userName, String videoURL, String downloadPath, BuildContext context) async {

String filename = "${userName}_${DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch}";
String downloadURL = videoURL;


String taskId = await FlutterDownloader.enqueue(
    url: downloadURL,
    savedDir: downloadPath,
    fileName: filename,
    showNotification: false,
    openFileFromNotification: false);

FlutterDownloader.registerCallback((id, status, progress) async {

  if (progress.toInt() >= 100) {

    String newFilename = "$filename.mp4";

    Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 500), () {
      File(downloadPath + "/" + filename)
          .renameSync(downloadPath + "/" + newFilename);
    });
  }
});
}
```

Comment: why dont you set the final filename? `String filename = '${userName}_${DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch}.mp4'`

Comment: I tried that too, but it doesn't work.

Comment: I believe flutter_downloader can only download normal video format, you can't download m3u8 format video, which is being used by many video web site.

Comment: I tried downloading without providing filename, it saved file with following name:

'57065846_2055402864557819_4971480998482966913_n.mp4?_nc_ht=scontent-dfw5-2.cdninstagram.com'

So, in this case i am getting ext but i have to rename anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I searched around and found that renaming video file will always mess up video codec settings, so best way is to handle it using FFMpeg.

```
import 'package:flutter_downloader/flutter_downloader.dart';
import 'package:flutter_ffmpeg/flutter_ffmpeg.dart';

class Download {

  final FlutterFFmpeg _flutterFFmpeg = FlutterFFmpeg();

  Future downloadMedia(String userName, String videoURL, String downloadPath, 
  BuildContext context) async {

    String filename = "${userName}_${DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch}";
    String filenameOriginal =
    "${userName}_${DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch}";
    String downloadURL = videoURL;
    var started = false;

    await FlutterDownloader.enqueue(
         url: downloadURL,
         savedDir: downloadPath,
         fileName: filename,
         showNotification: false,
         openFileFromNotification: false);


    FlutterDownloader.registerCallback((id, status, progress) async {

       if (progress.toInt() >= 100) {

          started = true;

          var inputFile = "${downloadPath + "/" + filename}";
          var outputFile = "${downloadPath + "/" + filenameOriginal}_${DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch}.mp4";

          _flutterFFmpeg
             .execute("-i inputFile -c copy outputFile")
          .then((rc) => print("FFmpeg process exited with rc $rc"));
          //Export file as Mp4 Video
       }
     });
   }
 }
```

Exported video file can easily be played in VLC player or MX player apps.